# Nginx asks for a password on every POST request

Tags: authentication, nginx

I closed the admin panel on a simple site with a password. When you log in, it asks for a password once and I can safely navigate through the pages. But as soon as I want to save the changes by sending the form a post request, Nginx asks for the password again. And so on every post request.

```
  server {
    server_name demo.app.ru;
    root /var/www/demo.app.ru/public_html;

    index index.html index.php;
    
    # Add trailing slash
    rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    # Remove repeating slashes
    if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*?//") {
        rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri permanent;
    }
    
    # Admin
    location ^~ /admin/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/demo.app.ru/.htpasswd;
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

I looked for answers on the Internet, but it feels like I'm the only one with this problem.

Comment: What is your admin page/admin? You can also check in your browser's network tab what initiates the calls that fail: Is it a submitted form or sent using javascript?

Comment: @ptts, thanks to your comment, I found an error, it was all about redirecting to http from https after saving the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The reason was an incorrect redirect after sending the form, there was a redirect to http instead of https.